# Cannot reproduce building static library

Tags: gcc, elf, objdump

I create a static library (`libxil.a`) (more precisely Xilinx's SDK generates a static library from BSP sources)

I realized that running `make` twice on the same sources produces different `libxil.a`. (The md5sum-s are different):

```
$ make
...

$ md5sum libxil.a
66f2a981ba0e608b4747d59c8d706561  libxil.a

$ make clean

$ make
...

$ md5sum libxil.a
ba26dba2211e539d0f17d9a4464b3386 libxil.a
```

I tried to view the difference with `objdump -s`, but nothing:

```
diff  <(objdump -s libxil1.a) <(objdump -s libxil2.a)
```

(`-s` *Display the full contents of all sections requested*)

How can I view the difference?

Why the two compilation differs at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-s` switch of `objdump` does not dump the headers. Use `-x` switch too, which *"Display the contents of all headers"*

```
$ diff  <(objdump -sx libxil1.a) <(objdump -sx libxil2.a)
...
4c4
< rw-rw-r-- 1008/1008   1324 Jul 24 10:36 2020 xio.o
---
> rw-rw-r-- 1008/1008   1324 Jul 24 10:46 2020 xio.o
...
```

A static library stores the creation date of the object files. And these timestamps differ compilation by compilation.

Comment: Note that using `ar D ...` when creating `lib*.a` will remove this source of irreproducibility.